# application size issue

Tags: java, android

I'm building a dictionary application and I have a problem right now. My application's is 16MB and when I install it on a phone, Database files copies to the data folder and in the manage apps section I see that my application size is 32MB (my app+data folder).

I don't cheat user, I want to say, my app is 16MB, but when user install it , it become 32MB. Why? this is a negative point and I want to solve it. I want my app uses only 16MB in users phone. just that

How I can fix this? I have to read and write in assets folder directly or there is other solution? this is a problem in low storage size phones. how I can fix this?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? you app needs 32MB space. Do you want to cheat that the user think it is only 16MB?

Comment: As I understand your application has 32MB because of file content, true?

Comment: @AlexWien: no, i dont cheat user, i want to say, my app is 16MB, but when user install it , it become 32MB. Why? this is a negative point and i want to solve it. i want my app uses only 16MB in users phone. just that

Comment: @AlexWien presumably Farhad wants to make the application only require 16 MB.  Downloading the database separately would do that.

Comment: @MaximShoustin: my app becomes 32MB because i install in the phone and database files copies from assets folder to data folder and this make it larger because my database files in assets folder still there. i cant remove it

Comment: aha, now its is more clear, you could update that info to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how your database is structured in terms of whether it is a pre-loaded database wherein you just include you .db file with all the data OR is it something where in you push all your DB content with the app and then at the time of app installation you actually install  all you data in the DB.

In case of the latter situation you double the size of your app because you already have data content (in files) which you want to use to populate your database (say 16 mb in this case). Then you use these files to actually create your DB file (which is 16mb again) and this doubles the size of the app.

So what you could do is pre-populate your DB content in a .db file and then just use this file   directly as the Db file in your app (this will keep it to 16mb). Follow this tutorial :

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, please re-read the 2nd paragraph of your link.  This method involves making a duplicate copy of the preloaded (and necessarily read-only) database to have a modifiable version. It might not double the size if the original is compressed in the apk, but there will be a definite size penalty as two copies of the information end up on the device.

Comment: @Farhad : Did this work out well for you ? How does your app size look like after using this technique ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your situation.

Do you have a roughly 16MB dictionary, that is packaged inside your app as string constants in your code or some resource file or something (to make it 16MB) and then, when your app installs or first launches, you also write this dictionary into your app's database?

If so, then now you have 2 copies of your dictionary around to make it 32MB.

To solve this, either keep only one copy in your app, or download the dictionary from somewhere to get it into your database rather than storing it as a constant in your app.

Comment: Downloading it is an option. But keeping only one copy of packaged in data is tricky, as the contents of an application's package cannot be modified by the application on the device.  Hence having only one copy would require some mechanism to separately store local changes against the unchangeable original.

Comment: my database files stored in the apk file. when i install it, it copied to user phone. but when user launch the app, my database file copies to the data folder and this make it twice larger. now, i have 2 copies of my database. and i cant delete the one copy inside assets folder because assets folder is read only.otherwise i need the other copy inside data folder because my app need it at runtime. how i can fix it? i don't want my app uses 32MB of users phone storage, but only 16MB and also my app works too. but whats is the solution

Comment: A dictionary sounds to me like a static data-structure that your app won't modify, correct? Couldn't you simply use the data directly rather than copying it? And if you're doing some processing on it before saving it to the database, try to pre-do the processing beforehand and have it already included in the apk file. On another note, you might also be able to compress your dictionary in the apk file (zip). That'll significantly speed up the install download as text usually compresses fairly well. But then you'd need to delete that compressed data, which unfortunately I don't know how, either.

Comment: no, i have some modification instructions on the database file and i cant use directly from assets folder because the assets folder is read only

Comment: @FarhadShirzad can you apply these modifications to your dictionary before you package it with your app?

Comment: @Markus: no i cant, i do some instructions like tagging a word or editing description of  a word...